# Can a huge amount of protons heavily packed cause electrical breakdown?

Tags: electrostatics, particle-physics, charge, conductors, coulombs-law

As far as I'm concerned, it's much more difficult for conductors to carry protons than electrons.

So, the internal charging limit equation (Q = E ε0 A) does not apply to proton charges? If not, **how would this exact equation be slightly changed.**

Comment: can you give a reference for the"limit equation" ?Normaly, as charges are arbitrarily assigned a + or -, one should expect no change in the  mathematics for a conductor of the type linked in the comment by john doty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_conductor . One needs to see how it is derived to see if something should change

Answer (score 0):

Conductors never propagate protons, except if you talk about fluid conductors. I solid conductors only electrons or positive so called holes move.

Comment: Not true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_conductor

Comment: Thak you for the correction, which I did not know